# how to stop triggering two event at a time in spark textarea (as3+flex4)

Tags: actionscript-3, events, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

textChanged and valueCommit both event listener are attached with a spark textarea as follows:

```
addEventListener("textChanged", 
    function(event:Event):void {                                    
        colorize();                 
},false,0,true);

addEventListener("valueCommit",
    function(event:Event):void {                    
        colorize();                 
},false,0,true);
```

if I type any thing in textarea, then this colorize() function is called twice. How can I stop this one that both event should not be triggered together. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen for typing, why do you have two listeners?  If you really need two listeners, you need to queue `colorize` with a `setTimeout` instead of calling it directly:

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

private var colorizeQueued:Boolean = false;
private function queueColorize():void
{
    if (colorizeQueued)
        return;

    colorizeQueued = true;
    setTimeout(function():void
    {
        // Process for real and note update
        colorize();
        colorizeQueued = false;
    }, 100);
}


addEventListener("textChanged", 
    function(event:Event):void {                                    
        queueColorize();                 
},false,0,true);

addEventListener("valueCommit",
    function(event:Event):void {                    
        queueColorize();           
},false,0,true);
```

Comment: @N Rohler: Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't it work with that solution and without the timeout?

Comment: @AntonPetrov: Basically, the `queueColorize` method does this: If it's the first time it has been called in a while, it calls `colorize`.  Otherwise, it says "I've been called recently, so I'm not going to do anything."

Comment: You didn't understand my question but i understood what i wanted to. Thanks.